# how to assign a function with arguments to a variable, then pass the variable to another function in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new to shell script, so any information is not trivial at all.
I'm writing a generic function `create_dir` that take a variable `$dirname` and an option variable `$function` to generate a directory. If the optional `$function` is absent, the default function is `mkdir`. Like this:

File `~/bin/lib/create_dir.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

create_dir()
{
    DIRNAME=$1
    FUNCTION=${2:-mkdir}
    $FUNCTION $DIRNAME
}
export -f create_dir
```

That works fine.

Now I import this into another file `~/bin/create_app`

```
#!/bin/bash
. "${HOME}/bin/lib/create_dir.sh"

DIRNAME=$1
FUNCTION="python manage.py startapp"

create_dir $FUNCTION $DIRNAME
```

When I run `create_app` it imported the `create_dir` but the variable `$FUNCTION` it feeds the `create_dir` is wrong. The variable `$FUNCTION` has only one word `python` instead of `python manage.py startapp` as I wanted.

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: You should quote the argument like this: `"$FUNCTION"`. Otherwise, the shell will run `create_dir python manage.py startapp ...` followed by all the words in the first argument to `create_app`. This way the first argument will be `python` and the second one `manage.py`

Comment: Stefan is right. Important rule in shell programming: When in doubt: quote. To check your scripts you can use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: oh my god I saw somewhere they emphasized the importance of putting variables between double quotes. Now I seee

Answer (score 0):

You should quote the argument like this: `"$FUNCTION"`. Otherwise, the shell will run

```
create_dir python manage.py startapp ...
```

followed by all the words in the first argument to `create_app`. This way the first argument to `create_dir` will be `python` and the second one `manage.py`.

You are always on the safe side if you put double quotes around your variable expansions. This will prevent the shell from splitting the value of that variable into separate words, which the function then regards as different arguments when you pass to it that variable as an argument.

There are cases where you can go without quotes, for example in the line

```
DIRNAME=$1
```

or more generally

```
var2=$var
```

as the bash will automatically assume that you want to assign the entire value of `var` to the variable `var2`. On the other hand, if you write the value directly, you need to use quotes:

```
string="Hello World"
```